# Is every intelligence a collection?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, intelligence, statistics

Is every intelligence a collection? Obviously 'general intelligence' is a collection of abilities, a statistical entity that is a measure of ability "in general". What about musical intelligence? Again, makes sense to say yes. Can any ability be named that is not composed of other skills?

The intelligence necessary to reproduce a "C" without a referent involves a cluster of processes, but is it a unitary ability? I would think maybe, but then, working up, where does that stop?

Comment: i suppose the obvious answer is "yes, but of what?"

Comment: The TLDR is that mind reduces to brain reduces to neural function in cognitive science.

Comment: so yes or no? it wasn't a long answer, and i did read it. my attention span is not so low. i find that idea startling @JD

Comment: It stops to God.

Comment: hm @IoannisPaizis personally, i'd think that any ability that can be represented as a yes/no might be unitary. iq doesn't work that way, as there are false positives and negatives.

Comment: The minimum stable system is triadic

Comment: i was just throwing that out there. i am really against the idea of iq testing for the sake of it, maybe becasue everyone is so greedy about it. iq =/= g, unlike a pitch test and pitch production. right @IoannisPaizis ?

Comment: the unintelligent trinity haha @IoannisPaizis

Comment: IQ is the assignment of a normed value based on time-constrained completion of language items and visual patterns and that value is purported to be a single-dimension representation of intelligence. There aren't false positives and negatives. If IQ is said to measure the G factor, the real debate is how meaningful the measure actually is with Gould famously weighing in against it. Of course, I'd rather be working with a bunch of people with IQs of 140 and above on language-based projects than others with an IQ of 80, so there's some utility as a shorthand for linguistic competence

Comment: i just meant for giftedness/ID etc. @JD same as any boundary you construct in testing

Comment: I agree with you that IQ is far too narrow to speak meaninfully about the full range of contributions a person can make in life. :D

Comment: @JD i would say the opposite, in a way. like, iq is a useful measure for predicting success in life, not really a measure of intelligence except in the abstract anyway. you seem to be ignoring a few things, but i don't want to argue so...

Comment: Famous college basketball coach said, "*You can't teach* height."

Comment: general intelligence definitely isn't *height* @ScottRowe

Comment: But clearly it has an effect and can't be taught. We may not know exactly what it is, but we know it is something.

Comment: i assumed we know what it is: a stastistical construct meant to capture what we mean by intelligence @ScottRowe that doesn't mean it's just imprecise. i think of it as shorthand for our expectations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Modularity of the mind (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modularity-mind/) is the article that covers the idea that the mind is not a monolithic entity. Marvin Minsky, Jerry Fodor, and other philosophers of mind recognize that if intelligence is a property of the mind, it is subject to decomposition. There are two popular theories of intelligence, [MI theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_multiple_intelligences) by Howard Gardner who represents a tradition of building that modularity into the description of intelligence (hence 'multiple intelligence theory') and the more traditional [G factor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_factor_(psychometrics)). Neither theory really conceives of intelligence as ultimately monolithic, and both theories have criteria for representing distinct subtypes of intelligence.

Both theories recognize [neural computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_computation) as the ultimate basis for thought and so intelligences weakly or strongly reduce to units of neural computation. Some theories of the emergence of grammars in Homo sapiens speak directly to the evolution of neurons providing capacities that precede certain intelligences, for instance, the use of grammar, by citing findings in [cognitive neuroscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_neuroscience) directly. It is thought that the neural computations for the fine motor control to manipulate the opposable thumb in the human hand opened the pathway to greater mass in the associative and neocortices to develop concomitantly with manipulating the environment and language use.

**Thus, yes, acts of mental intelligence in modern cognitive science are reduced to collections of neural computation, and that's where intelligence is grounded.**

Comment: In AI, one will often hear about simulated intelligence being grounded in computational models which are statistical rather than symbolic models. Hence, there are genetic algorithms, ML, ANNs, swarm models, etc. The adjective applied in this case may be 'sub-symbolic', and such models of intelligence are often referred to in the spirit of Thorndike as [connectionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionism).

Comment: Sorry I didn't make the answer more explicit. It is a resounding yes that intelligences are reduced to sub-intelligences which are themselves collections of neural computations, in the view of cognitive science, at least. Philosophy of mind does admit other, non-scientific theories, such as the Monads of Leibniz, for instance.

Comment: yeah, there's not much to disagree with there.

Comment: How can anything be monolithic? not even an atom is.

Comment: @IoannisPaizis It's pretty hard to conceive of, but I believe Parmenides argued the entire universe was a unified whole, so if you simply argue every distinction is a part of something bigger, you get into some metaphysical disputes that may or may not depend on the definition of 'monolithic'.

Comment: monolithic abstract entities? i have read that a few decades ago ppl thought it was a measure of how fast the neurons in your brain tend to propagate. totally insane

Comment: anyway, do you really believe that any system can be regulated by the sum of its parts?

Comment: Somehow I suspect we agree, but the conclusion of your answer does not seem compatible with this.

Comment: @IoannisPaizis Some systems, sure. Consider a direct democracy. Decisions are made regarding regulation by the sum of the parts. That sum is called a vote.

Comment: Not in an idealized direct democracy. Each part, the voter, regulates himself by respecting the outcome of the vote. No top-down regulation required. Now, in practice, many people in a democracy don't respect the democratic process, and as such some group is tasked with regulating those who do not respect the process. In the US, this is called the executive branch and law enforcement.

Comment: I get the point, but the individual vote in such a system is considering the benefit of the whole.

Comment: Think of this: The law causes organization, or the organization makes the law.

Comment: uhh so wtf do you think iq is @IoannisPaizis ? talk about f silly reifications.

Answer (score 1):

Intellectual narcissism says one's intelligence is composed of a single thing, whatever that is (brain size, neuron speed, some other status symbol) and however general it is (musical genius, love of the deity). Reducing raw abilities to the brain would be an antidote to that, if we keep our wits (which is too much to ask for many). But yeah, no way is general intelligence not 'warm' enough: it is a phantom next to both actual achievement and individual skills.

Comment: Not all tall people are good basketball players (speaking from my experience). The variation is mostly due to practice. That's how you get to Carnegie Hall. But being very good at one thing helps little or not at all with anything else. Great musical performers are rarely also great chefs or physicists. (And *wars not make one great*, as we know) So, modularity seems to be proven.

Answer (score 0):

Collection does not cover it. I propose synthesis as a better term.